# In .net, is there a way for my CustomButton.vb to have a CustomButton.resx?

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, embedded-resource

I have a .NET class, `CustomButton`, that inherits `Control`. So I have a `CustomButton.vb` file that looks like

```
Public Class CustomButton
    Inherits Control

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

with all the properties that I want to override. When I use the class, I go to existing and link it into the current project. The class maybe linked into more than one project.

If you create a custom form and embed an image into it, a .resx file is created.

So my question….
In one of my sub/function I want something such as `Me.BackgroundImage = x` where x will be an image. If I did `Me.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.x` then I would have to include x into every project that I linked the custom class into. Is there a way for my `CustomButton.vb` to have a `CustomButton.resx`? If so I would I access an image in it call `Red.x`?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *three* files you have to get included in any project, CustomButton.vb, CustomButton.resx and CustomButton.Designer.vb.  The latter one is hidden in VB.NET but required to get the My.Resources syntax going.  Click the Show All Files button in the Solution Explorer toolbar to see it, expand the .resx node.

A class library project ought to be high on your list of preferred approaches.  Also a hard requirement to get it permanently in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

What [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) said, got me headed in the right direction.

I not sure how the original `.vb` file was started, but there was no `.designer.vb` or `.resx`. I copied a `.resx` from a form and renamed it to my `.vb` file. With the `.designer.vb` I saw two of the same class names. When I excluded the `.designer.vb` file one of them when away. 
Here is how I got it to work. Taking what *@Hans Passant* said I looked at the form and how it reference the resource.

```
Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(xxxx))
```

Where xxxx is the name of the class. Then added the .png file to the resouce and gave it a name yyyy.

```
Me.BackgroundImage = CType(resources.GetObject("yyyy"), System.Drawing.Image)
```